# Is there a way to tail logs on a remote Windows machine from Mac?

Tags: windows, macos, logging, tail

I use a Mac (Mtn Lion) at work, but all our servers are Windows based. It would be great to view logs in real time, is there a way for me to do that?

I suppose I could remote into the machines, but that isn't very convenient. Right now I just have to mount the log share on the Windows machine in Finder using SMB and open the log files with a text editor, then reopen them for the latest data.

Thanks!

Comment: Why? Don't you have a `tail` utility for the Mac?

Comment: @theglauber I think user1916727 already tried with "tail" command. I have the same problem: seems that SMB from Windows do not updates files in real time, but have a long delay. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Hmm. I don't have Mac, so i can't help much, but i did a quick web search and found something that could be related: [Slow SMB Browsing from Mac to Windows](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20110430173901534). The suggestion is to make a few edits on `smb.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

use `tail -f` in osx terminal window

Answer (score 0):

I typically use "tail -f" for this. In Linux it works perfectly also for files in mounted SMB shares.

I noticed that tail is not working instead in the same context in Mac OS. It does not follow properly. To overcome this issue, use gtail instead. You can istall gtail from macports. That follows properly even on Windows shares mounted through Finder on Mac OS.